# Why can't a hexadecimal integer constant be negative?

Tags: c, integer, constants, literals

[This table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant#The_type_of_the_integer_constant) shows type is the first type in which the value can fit. Examining `0xFFFFFFF0` with gdb shows it to be an `unsigned type`:

```
(gdb) ptype 0xFFFFFFF0
type = unsigned int
```

But `0xFFFFFFF0` is `-16` when interpreted as a signed integer so why can't it fit in the `int` type? Doing the same with a decimal input shows the desired type:

```
ptype -16
type = int
```

I also wanted to ask about this sentence in the same link above:

> There are no negative integer constants. Expressions such as -1 apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the constant, which may involve implicit type conversions.

So -1 = 0 -1 = -1, AKA a negative integer? I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: It is implementation defined how signed integers are internally represented.

Comment: there is no such thing as a `hexadecimal integer`, only hexadecimal representation of a number. In your case a hexadecimal literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no negative integer constants in C.

The grammar for integer constants is:

- A decimal constant is a sequence of decimal digits not starting with `0` and with an optional suffix (`u` and/or `l` or `ll` in either order with any cases [uppercase or lowercase]).
- An octal constant is a sequence of octal digits starting with `0` and an optional suffix.
- A hexadecimal constant is `0x` followed by a sequence of hexadecimal digits, with any cases.

None of those have a minus sign. All integers constants in C are numerals with nonnegative values. Where a minus sign appears with a constant in C code, as in `-34`, it is two separate tokens: a unary negation operator followed by a constant.

The goal of selecting a type for a constant is to select a type that can represent its value. As a hexadecimal numeral, the value of FFFFFFF0<sub>16</sub> is 4,294,967,280. If `0xFFFFFFF0` were made a 32-bit `int`, the value of that int would be −16 in two’s complement or some other values in one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude. It would not be 4,294,967,280. So a 32-bit `int` cannot represent the value of this numeral, so the compiler does not use a 32-bit `int` for the type.

There are also no negative floating-point constants. Enumeration constants and character constants can be negative in some circumstances.

Comment: So what does `int a = 5 - 6;` mean? is it interpreted as `int a = 5 + (0 - 6);` we don't have a `negative six` immediate input here?

Comment: @Dan: `int a = 5 - 6;` is parsed as the tokens `int` `a` `=` `5` `-` `6` `;`. Then the grammar rules of C make `-` into a binary subtraction operator, not a unary negation operator.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the constant being hex -- it has solely to do with the value of the constant and how many bits it.

The rules for typing of constant literals (without type suffixes) are pretty simple.  It simply checks to see if the value is in range for various signed and unsigned integer types, starting with int and going to progressively larger types, until it finds one that fits.  It tries the signed type of a given size before the unsigned type of that size.

The same thing happens if you use a decimal int:

```
(gdb) ptype 4294967280
type = unsigned int
```

here 4294967280 is the deciaml value of 0xfffffff0.  Since this value is out of range for `int` but in range for `unsigned int`, that's what it is.  Try a number with one more digit (hex or decimal) and you'll get `long long` as it is out of range for `unsigned int`.

Using a negative number, you'll generally get a signed type:

```
(gdb) ptype -0x10
type = int
```

however, the `-` isn't really part of the constant, it is an operator applied to the literal and does not affect its type.  So you see

```
(gdb) p 0xfffffff0
$1 = 4294967280
(gdb) p -0xfffffff0
$2 = 16
(gdb) ptype -0xfffffff0
type = unsigned int
(gdb) ptype 4294967280
type = unsigned int
(gdb) p -4294967280
$3 = 16
(gdb) ptype -4294967280
type = unsigned int
```

Note the last one -- a decimal constant that is too big for `int` (but in range for `unsigned`) giving a suprising output.  This despite the fact that the C spec seems to unambiguously state that decimal constants will always be signed, rather than unsigned, regardless of the value.

with bigger numbers

```
(gdb) p 0xffffffff0
$4 = 68719476720
(gdb) ptype 0xffffffff0
type = long long
(gdb) p -0xffffffff0
$5 = -68719476720
```

Comment: ok then `0xFFFFFFF0` should be of type `int`, it fits perfectly fine, its -16.

Comment: Its not `-16` -- that would be `-0x10`

Comment: Note that `-0x10` is not an integer constant.  It is an an expression involving the unary `-` operator (and an integer constant).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Neither is `-16` -- it is likewise an expression involving a unary `-` and an integer.

Comment: Quite so.  The point is that there aren't any negative integer constants.

Comment: Ok then can I say, integer constants (whether in decimal format or hex) are always positive and interpreted as an unsigned positive constant. I need to manually apply the `-` sign like `-16`, which does a `0-<constant> or 0-16` operation behind the scene and could yield a negative result?

Comment: They're always positive, but may be treated as either a signed or an unsigned type, depending on the value.

Comment: depending on the **final** value right? after the possible unary sign operation.

Comment: Re “The rules for typing of constant literals are pretty simple. It simply checks to see if the value is in range for various signed and unsigned integer types,…”: That is not the rule for constant literals. It is the rule for unsuffixed octal or hexadecimal constants. For unsuffixed decimal constants, unsigned types are not considered. With a `u` suffix, signed types are not considered. With an `l` or `ll` suffix, consideration starts at `long` or `long long` (without a `u`) or their corresponding unsigned types (with a `u`).

Comment: No, depending solely on the (positive) value of the literal.  Unless you put a type suffix on the literal, in which case that controls the type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: gdb seems to disagree with you, as you can see above,

Comment: @ChrisDodd: The rules are as specified in C 2018 6.4.4.1 5 regardless of how gdb behaves.

Comment: gdbs output is a bit strange: `p /d 0xfffffff0` shows -16, `p /d -0x10` also shows -16.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Using Apple Clang 11.0, `#include <stdio.h>` / `int main(void) { printf("%s\n", _Generic(4294967280, int: "int", unsigned: "unsigned", long: "long", unsigned long: "unsigned long", long long: "long long", unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", default: "unknown")); }` prints “long”, consistent with the C standard and differing from your gdb example. gdb is wrong regarding `4294967280`.

Comment: @Dan, [The `/d` in `p /d` explicitly requests GDB to interpret the data being printed as a *signed* integer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html#Output-Formats).  If you use `p /u` then you will get the unsigned interpretation.  You cannot use these outputs to determine which, if either, the C language specifies the integer constant `0x10` to mean.

Answer (score 1):

**Shorten answers**

> Why can't a hexadecimal integer constant be negative?

In C, all integer constants are non-negative (0 or more) as that is how the language is defined.

> But 0xFFFFFFF0 is -16 when interpreted as a signed integer so why can't it fit in the int type?

The first type `0xFFFFFFF0` fits in is `unsigned`, not `int` as is greater than `INT_MAX`.

> Doing the same with a decimal input shows the desired type: ptype -16 type = int

`16` fits in an `int`, so it is an `int`.  After the type is determined, the negating of that is well defined, so the value of the expression is `-16`.

> So -1 = 0 -1 = -1, AKA a negative integer? I don't understand this sentence.

Consider `-1` and `0 - 1` employ the `int` constants `0` and `1` and are expressions both with a value of -1 and type of `int`.

Comment: in `-0xFFFFFFF0` is `-` always ignored when deducing the type? the type is always deduced by interpreting the literal itself? In a c++ expression of `auto a = -0xFFFFFFF0;`, how is `a` interpreted as? I'm going to assume type of the literal is taken from `0xFFFFFFF0` which makes it an unsigned int. Then `0-0xFFFFFFF0` is preformed . Now how is the result of this expression treated as? a Hex type or a decimal type? What about `auto a = 0xFFFFFFF0`?

Comment: @Dan The `-` plays no part in determining the constant's type.

Comment: Yes seems like `auto a = -0xFFFFFFF0;` and `auto a = 0xFFFFFFF0;` both treat `a` as an unsigned int. The literal itself is the key.

Comment: @Dan `0-0xFFFFFFF0` is an `int` - `unsigned`.  The `int` is converted to an `unsinged` and the the difference is calculated as an `unsigned`.

Comment: But in the expression `auto a = -0xFFFFFFF0;`, is the compiler interpreting it as `auto a = 0 - 0xFFFFFFF0;` ? is this what the *apply the unary minus operator* sentence talking about?

Comment: @dan In C, 0xFFFFFFF0 is specified as a _constant_, not a _literal_.  C has _string literals_ and _compound literals_.  What other languages do might be of tangential interest, yet they do not define C.  For a C++ answer, best to post a C++ question.

Comment: ok but why im trying to understand the *apply the unary minus operator* part, is my example above showing this, is `auto a = -0xFFFFFFF0;` interpreted as `auto a = 0 - 0xFFFFFFF0;`? if not could you please show an example of it?

Comment: I'd rather not bring is a C++ discussion here to the C question and answer.  From a C POV `0 - 0xFFFFFFF0` is an `unsigned` with a value of 16 when `unsigned` is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

> But 0xFFFFFFF0 is -16 when interpreted as a signed integer so why can't it fit in the int type?

When you say "interpreted as", you are failing to distinguish between an external representation of a number and an internal one.  I presume that the fact that the constant in question is expressed in hexadecimal is contributing to this error. I doubt you would suggest that 4294967280 should be interpreted as -16 (decimal), yet that is exactly analogous to what you are suggesting for the hexadecimal version.

The fact is that hexadecimal integer constants are not to be interpreted as bit patterns for this purpose.  They are hexadecimal representations of numbers.  They are implicitly positive, there being no mechanism provided in the lexical form of an integer constant to express a negative number.  (Negative numbers can be formed as *expressions* involving integer constants and the unary `-` operator.)

Among other things, this supports portability, as C does not specify the exact sizes of the various integer types, and implementations do vary in practice.  C also allows three different choices for the representation of negative integers, though these days implementatoins pretty consistently use twos complement format. A given integer constant, whether expressed in octal, decimal, or hexadecimal, will be interpreted as the same numeric value by every C implementation (though there may be some that have no data type that can represent that value).